# Using HTTP_HOST in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using this to force https and www via htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Now I want to change the `R=302` in `R=301`, and ditch the domain name itself. The reason why I don't want example.com to be in there is because it might be that for some countries the domain name will be different in the future.

So I was thinking

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

... but that would redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to [www.www.example.com](http://www.www.example.com) right?
How to do this properly in this specific case? I still want to force www and https in one single redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still want to force www and https in one single redirect.

You need to use this redirect rule like this to avoid hardcoding:

```
# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```